# What is the use of Materialized View in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, view, materialized-views

I am making a dashboard system feature where i have a view for a specific report, the database I'm using is PostgreSQL. I plan to turn it to a materialized view to optimize it, but it will make the dashboard's data not real time, so i plan to refresh the materialized view every time the source table's data is updated. But, after reading the documentation here:
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-refreshmaterializedview.html

It said that REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW just completely replaces the contents of a materialized view, thus lowering the performance when updating the base table. That made me wonder, is there actually a good use for materialized views?

Comment: You always need to balance between "quick to write, slow to read" and "slow to write, quick to read". This is one of those moments where you need to explore both materialized and non-materialized approaches. A materialized view can help considerably when you write it a small number of times, and read from it a ton, effectively amortizing the write cost across many, many reads.

Comment: How many updates per second/minute/hour do you have? And when the base query is fast enough, there is no need to materialize it.

Answer (score 2):

A materialized view is a tool that allows queries that would otherwise take too long to complete quickly, at the price of working with slightly stale data. You use it if you cannot find a better solution.

Answer (score 1):

A Materialized View in your situation (a dashboard) has plenty of value.

A View takes a query and allows you to call that query `Q` and retrieve its results as somewhat of a shortcut.  However, when you call the View, it executes query `Q` every time and gets the real-time results, meaning that if the query `Q` takes a long time (i.e., 5-10 seconds, or however you would define "a long time"), you could see users of your dashboard getting frustrated at the slowness.

In the case of a Materialized View, the query `Q` is executed once, and its results are saved.  When you retrieve information from the Materialized View, it can take (for example) <1 second every time, depending on your data set instead of 5-10 seconds.  This would be a faster experience for your dashbaord users.  And then refreshing the Materialized View would take the amount of time to execute query `Q` (5-10 seconds).  In this hypothetical example, an occasional call to `Q` that takes 5-10 seconds so that users can get data in <1 second is far more efficient than those users having to wait 5-10 seconds every time.